# Animated lighting in amusement parks

Tags: unity, lighting

What is the best way to handle animated lights on rides in a night time amusement park scene?

Is there a better way that doing lots of emission lights?

At the moment I have been using emission lights, but there could be a lot of them in a park (some are just static lights) and I would also like to animate some of them on some rides.

Best example I could find was from GTA 5:

[image: img]

Video: https://youtu.be/zVj8D0lqgl4?t=146

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just an animated [emissive texture](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StandardShaderMaterialParameterEmission.html) that ignores incoming light. If you don't need them to actually provide light to the surrounding geometry the set the global illumination parameter for them to none and they will be cheap.